# How to enable Google Ads Data Hub Account? Your account may not be associated with an active Ads Data Hub customer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to activate Google Ads Hub Account. We have Google Cloud account and my user has full control over the account. Does anybody know how to activate Ads Data Hub account ? :)

When I'm trying to access the interface of Ads Data Hub: https://adsdatahub.google.com/ I'm getting an error message "You do not have access to this application. Your account may not be associated with an active Ads Data Hub customer."

Link to support doesn't work: https://support.google.com/ads-data-hub/contact/adh_support

I found this article: https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/account-setup which has a "Note: This guide assumes that you are the owner of both the Ads Data Hub account" so I probably already need to have some access to the Ads Data Hub in order to proceed... And when I'm trying to find Ads Data Hub API in list of Services/APIs it is not there neither...

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, if you will be activating the API, the account you are using should already be linked to a Google Ads account. You can create your Google ads account [here](https://ads.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I already have Google Ads account, what I need is Google Ads Data Hub account 

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having same issue, Goolge support doesn't help

Comment: Hi, nope 
However support finally admitted that the service is in some kind of testing mode and not publicly available.

So we gave up. Perhaps you could try to contact one of partners (I think in the documentation there was a link to a page with companies who can help with Ads Data Hub)